# Argument out of range exception during substring

Tags: vb.net

hi i have a string like this:

```
CurrentDate-[8]>15&CurrentDate-[8]<1000&[11]=HANWHA
```

and i want to cut it to 3 strings like :

```
CurrentDate-[8]>15
CurrentDate-[8]<1000
[11]=HANWHA
```

this is my function to cut the formula

```
Public Shared Function Cut(formula As String, numberOfConditions As Integer) As String()
    Dim Parts(numberOfConditions) As String

    Dim startPoint As Integer = 0
    Dim curCondition As Integer = 0

    For i As Integer = 0 To formula.Length() - 1
        If formula(i) = "&" Then
            Parts(curCondition) = formula.Substring(startPoint, i - 1) ' here error occures when curCond = 1

            curCondition += 1
            startPoint = i + 1

        End If
    Next

    Parts(curCondition) = formula.Substring(startPoint)

    Return Parts
End Function
```

During error when i start function formula is what i have written above and numberOfConditions is 2.
So i make array (0-2) and want to put there parts. But during curCcondition = 1 i get thet when i want to substring from 19 to 39 (formula lenght is 59). How is it possible ?

And the last step is to substring the last element (eg. when there is no & i don't want to cut anything or to get the last part (I don't end last part with &))

Anyone could help me?

Comment: wrap your substring line in an if statement **if(MyString.Length>=startPoint)**

Comment: Also, you should look into using the **String.Split** method. It might be easier to implement if there is a certain delimiting character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second parameter in `String.Substring(startPoint, i - 1)`  is not the end-index but the length.  So you need to subtract the index from  the startpoint:

```
Parts(curCondition) = formula.Substring(startPoint, i - startPoint )
```

By the way, you can get the same result in a much more readable way using `String.Split`:

```
Dim cut = "CurrentDate-[8]>15&CurrentDate-[8]<1000&[11]=HANWHA".Split({"&"c}, 3)
```

Comment: @JakubWisniewski: note that i've edited it, you could use `String.Split` for the same.

Comment: and in split 3 is how many splits ? and what c stands for ? cut?

Comment: @JakubWisniewski: `"&"c` is a character, the `c` tells the compiler that this is a `Char`-literal(same as apostrophes in C#). So `{"&"c}` is a `Char()` with a single character. The 3 ist just the overload of string.split which can be used to specify the max-count of parts that should be splitted. So if there are more than three parts you would still get only the first three. This is the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1bs0eda(v=vs.110).aspx